# Dirac delta function?

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta

I am reading the paper http://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/Convolution.pdf with the goal of learning about convolutions. In the paper, the unit function is defined as
$$
\delta_T (t) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & t \leq 0 \\
      1/T & 0 < t \leq T \\
      0 & t > 0
   \end{cases}
$$
and then defines the Dirac Delta function as $\delta(t) = \lim_{T \rightarrow 0} \delta_T(t)$.

What then confuses me is that he says that

> An impulse occurring at $t = a$ is $\delta(t-a)$

I cannot see why this is true with the definition of the unit function above. For example if $t = a \leq T$, wouldn't $\delta(t) = 1/T$ and $\delta(t-a) = 0$? Thus, $\delta(t) \neq \delta(t-a)$ as he claims?

Wiki is using the same definition of unit function(as far as I can see) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Comment: The exposition on Wikipedia actually uses a slightly different approach:  they define a *nascent Delta "function"* to be a Gaussian (i.e. $$\eta_{\varepsilon} := \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \eta\left( \frac{x}{\varepsilon} \right), $$ where $\eta(x) := \chi_{[-1,1]}(x) \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}}$.  The advantage of this approximation scheme is that all of the nascent functions are smooth (infinitely differentiable).

Comment: That being said, from a distributional point of view, the end result is the same---that is, $\delta = \lim_{T\to 0} \delta_T = \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \eta_{\varepsilon}$.  Here, the limit is taken in the appropriate space of generalized functions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in the lecture notes:

$$
\delta_T (t) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & t \leq 0 \\
      1/T & 0 < t \leq T \\
      0 & \color{red}{t > T}
   \end{cases}
$$

(You can find this typo by looking at the picture in Figure 1(a) of your linked notes.)

Now, if you shift this function, you get
$$
\delta_T (t-a) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & t \leq a \\
      1/T & a < t \leq T \\
      0 & \color{red}{t > T+a}
   \end{cases}
$$

Now by **definition**,

$$
\delta(t-a)=\lim_{T\to 0}\delta_T(t-a)
$$

---

Note: you read the definition of $\delta$ incorrectly:
$$
\delta(t)=\lim_{\color{red}{T}\to 0}\delta_T(t)
$$

Comment: Oh so it was actually a typo... Thank you!

Comment: @Dip: you are welcome! let me know if you have further question.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\delta_T (t-a) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & t-a \leq 0 \\
      1/T & 0 < t-a \leq T \\
      0 & t-a > T.
   \end{cases}
$$

If you prefer,

$$
\delta_T (t-a) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & t \leq a \\
      1/T & a < t \leq a+T \\
      0 & t > a+T.
   \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Ahh thanks for that! But now that I think about it, I might not understand such a definition in the first place: So it says that if $t \leq 0$, the value is 0, if $0 < t \leq T$, the value is $1/T$ but also that $t > 0$, the value is 0? I mean, if $0 < t \leq T$ it must imply that $t > 0$, i.e. an overlap -- so isn't there something wrong with the definition or is there something I do not understand(likely this option)?

Comment: @Dip: I copied blindly from your post and substituted $x$ for $x-a$. Indeed, there is a typo in the third clause.